# Filter similar names in object array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

so here is a problem I've been struggling with for a little bit now. I want to filter a list of objects but the code seems to work only for arrays. I can i reach the same result with objects? Basically what I want is something like: if card.name = jose. then remove jose._R
if card.name = jose._R then remove jose.

Code:

```
var data = {'cards' : 
    [
    {'name': "jose."}, 
    {'name': "jose._R"}, 
    {'name': "rodrigo."}, 
    {'name': "rodrigo._R"}, 
    {'name': "jojo."}, 
    {'name': "jojo._R"},
    ]
    };
    
let dataName = data.cards[0].name;
let rev = data.cards[0].name + "_R";

var data2 = ["jose.", "jose._R", "rodrigo.", "rodrigo._R", "jojo.", "jojo._R",];
let dataName2 = data2[0];
let rev2 = data2[0] + "_R";


if(dataName2.endsWith('.')){
    data2 = data2.filter(function(f) {return f !== rev2});
};

if(dataName.endsWith('.')){
    data = data.cards.filter(function(f) {return f !== rev}); // NOT WORKING! It doesn't remove the object array... :-(
};

console.log(data);
console.log(data2);
```

Comment: Can the OP please provide the exact comparison scenario in terms of ... in case one provides information X one expects result Y. Otherwise, with the current provided initial condition the OP will end with an empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your filter function

```js
function(f) { 
  return f !== rev; 
}
```

You are comparing the *entire object* `{ 'name': 'rodrigo.' }` to the string so they will never be equal. Instead you should compare the name property with the given string:

```js
function(f) {
  return f.name !== rev;
}
```